# swift - error when drawing curve

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I am attempting to write a program that draws a curve.  The shorter the curve, the closer to green it gets.  Here is the code for drawing the circle:

```
func drawCircle(percent: CGFloat) {
    // Set up all the data for the circle
    let redAmt = 1 / 100 * percent
    let greenAmt = 1 - redAmt
    let circleColor = UIColor.init(red: redAmt, green: greenAmt, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    let lineWidth = CGFloat(12)
    let centerX = self.frame.size.width / 2
    let centerY = self.frame.size.height / 2
    let radius = (self.frame.size.width - lineWidth) / 2
    // Clear the area where the circle is going to be drawn
    let clearCirclePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
    clearColor.setStroke()
    clearCirclePath.lineWidth = lineWidth
    clearCirclePath.stroke()
    // Draw the circle
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2) * percent / 100, clockwise: true)
    circleColor.setStroke()
    circlePath.lineWidth = lineWidth
    circlePath.stroke()
}
```

It works just fine when called by `drawRect(rect: CGRect)`, but when I try to call in another file, it does not work.  It is drawing the arc in a view inside a view controller.  The error it gives me is this: `ExerciseTracker[7270] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.`

Thanks a lot!

(I am using Xcode 7.3.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must draw in a valid context. `drawRect:` provides such a valid context. Simply putting code outside of `drawRect:` doesn't work unless you explicitly create your own context such as a bitmap context for creating an image by drawing.

The code in your `drawCircle` method needs to be in the `drawRect:` method of a custom view class. Instead of passing `percent` as a parameter, set it as an instance variable. Then anytime you update the value of `percent`, you call `setNeedsDisplay()` to trigger the view to redraw itself.